# make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2 make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: compiling, gcc

I tried to install MADWIFI on my OpenMediaVault-Server. Any more information needed?

I get this error, every time i enter `make`:

```
root@NAS2024:/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4# make
Checking requirements... ok.
Checking kernel configuration... ok.
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
  CC [M]  /media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.o
/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1: error: bad value (armv4) for -march= switch
make[5]: *** [/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4/ath] Error 2
make[3]: *** [_module_/media/5703066A59887FF7/Dsys/madwifi-0.9.4] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
make: *** [modules] Fehler 2
```

Why has this error occured?

Comment: Welcome to unix.SE.  What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Karlson How can i fix this error an continue with installing? Why is there a error?

Comment: Looks like your compiler doesn't support the `armv4` target architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the details on how to cross compile the MadWifi drivers for other architectures. Such as in your case you're attempting to compile for ARM4, though perhaps not intentionally.

- http://madwifi-project.org/svn/madwifi/branches/madwifi-0.9.4/INSTALL

*excerpt*

> #### Cross-compiling
>
> The build system is designed to support cross-compiling without any
>   modification to the distribution files.  It should be sufficient to
>   specify any parameters on the make command line.
>
> In most cases, only KERNELPATH and CROSS_COMPILE need to be defined. 
>   CROSS_COMPILE is the prefix for cross-compiling tools.  For instance, if
>   the cross compiler is called arm-linux-gcc, set CROSS_COMPILE to
>   "arm-linux-":
>
> ```
>     $ make KERNELPATH=/usr/src/linux-arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
> ```
>
> The build system determines ARCH and TARGET based on the .config file in
>   the Linux build tree.  TARGET still may need to be provided on the
>   command line some uncommon systems.  If ARCH is determined incorrectly,
>   please report it.

Comment: Result:

`# make KERNELPATH=/usr/src/linux-arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-`
`cd: 1: can't cd to /usr/src/linux-arm
Makefile.inc:66: *** /usr/src/linux-arm is missing, please set KERNELPATH.  Schluss.`